# How to ignore sql errors in stored procedure ? (Not handle)

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, error-handling

I have a list of records I want to process and the cursor iterates through them from a table. The procedure just exits when it hits an insert statement and it fails. Is there a way I can ignore the errors and continue processing the following records ?

Cursor C1:
for each record:
    insert into table_t1(col1) values ('...');  <-- Insert statement fails for record 'n'
End cursor

I would like for it to not exit out but continue processing from n+1 to the end of cursor.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can always catch the error and CHOOSE to do nothing about it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it.

You have to declare a continue handler instead of an exit handler. That way even if there is an exception, it goes into the handler and continues with the next record.

> DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING
>
> > BEGIN
> >      ...
> >      Code that handles the exception/warning
> >      ...
> >     END